# Yii CGridView does not show default filters

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am trying to render a CGridView widget with Yii and despite the table is correct, it does not include the filter input.

My widget code in the view is the following:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'awesomeGrid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'enableSorting'=>true,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    /*array('name'=>'Check',
        'value'=>'CHtml::checkBox("name",true)',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>5),
),*/
    array(
        'header'=>'Prueba_Columna',
        'name'=>'OBJECT_TYPE',
        'value'=>'$data->OBJECT_TYPE',
        'filter'=>$model->getFilter(),
        'type' => 'raw'),

)
));
?>
```

My model is:

```
public function search(){
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria->select='OBJECT_TYPE';
   return new CActiveDataProvider($this,array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
       'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20)
    ));



}
public function getFilter(){
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('OBJECT_TYPE',$this->OBJECT_TYPE,true);
   return new CActiveDataProvider($this,array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));



}
```

And my controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $appUsersModel    = new AppUsers(); //Instance the model object
    $objectsListModel = new ObjectsList('search');
    $objectsUserModel = new ObjectUser();

    $appsArray     = $this->getApps($appUsersModel);
    $projectsArray = $this->getProjects($objectsListModel);
    $usersArray    = array(array());
    $typesArray    = array(array());
    $objectsArray  = array(array());

    // renders the view file 'protected/views/security/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->render('index',
        array('appsArray' => $appsArray,
        'usersArray' => $usersArray,
        'projectsArray' => $projectsArray,
        'typesArray' => $typesArray,
        'objectsArray' => $objectsArray,
        'appUsersModel' => $appUsersModel,
        'objectsUserModel' => $objectsUserModel,
        'model'=>$objectsListModel,
        )
    );
}
```

When I go to the developers tools on firefox and check whether the HTML is correct I see the following:

```
<div id="awesomeGrid" class="grid-view">
<div class="summary">Displaying 1-20 of 2432 results.</div>
<table class="items">
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="awesomeGrid_c0"><a class="sort-link" href="/apps/project_name/web/index.php/security/index?ObjectsList_sort=OBJECT_TYPE">Prueba_Columna</a></th></tr>
    <tr class="filters">
    <td></td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
    <td>VIEW</td></tr>
    <tr class="even">
    <td>VIEW</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

As you can see there is `<tr class="filters"><td></td></tr>` tag but does not exists the input tag inside to filter. Then I think that the widget is propertly configured, but maybe there is some mistake that makes the input is not showed.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Filter should be a `array`. Have you checked your output of `getFilter()`. It seems it doesn't return `array`. That's why you are not getting filter. Try to see output of your `function`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The output is:

CActiveDataProvider Object.

What kind of values should have the array?

Thanks

Comment: what you need in that field means which select box ?? convert object in your desired array ?? or please update your question with function output and desired filter dropdown you want

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get a solution, as I told you I am using Yii, but I did not generate the model with Gii, so the rules function was empty.

I defined a return array on that function that makes the field able to be searched.

The code is:

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(

                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('OBJECT_TYPE', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );

    }
```

Thanks all for your replies.